# having multiple cores in a gem5 SE script

Tags: gem5

I'm new to working with gem5 and I'm having this question:
till now I have only used one CPU in my system by setting system.cpu = myCpu in the python script.
But now I want to have multiple CPUs in the system and assign different processes to them, how can I place all {myCpu1, myCpu2 , ...} in the system and have them run their own process during run-time?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but here are some related (not very unsatisfactory) threads: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg15336.html | https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg15346.html